# BeautifulSoup randomly gets stuck in for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I’ve been using BeautifulSoup to extract multiple pages of reviews from websites, and it’s worked wonders mostly but on large datasets has constantly been getting stuck at seemingly random points.

My code is always along the lines of the following.

```
for x in range(len(reviews)):
    reviewsoups.append(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(reviews[x]).text, ‘html.parser))
```

I’ve never gotten any errors or anything (except the random ConnectionReset error), but it just seems as though the loop gets stuck randomly to the point where I consistently have to interrupt the kernel (which often takes 10+ minutes to actually work) and restart the process from the index where the loop got stuck.

It seems as though in some cases, if I try and use my laptop whatsoever while the code is running (like opening Chrome etc) that aggravates the situation.

Can anyone help? It’s just incredibly irritating having to sit by my laptop waiting just in case something like this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're running out of memory. The symptoms you report point to something of the sort. Is it really necessary to create all of the `soup`s before processing any of them? They are quite big, you know.

Comment: I’m afraid that’s what I’m trying to do. The dataset I’m currently working with has 9000+ URLs and each soup will contain up to 30 reviews, so I need to process all of them. 

More often than not the loop will get stuck and then continue after 15-20 minutes but I always get worried and terminate, in fear of it crashing my computer resulting in a force restart and hence having to restart the entire loop (takes several hours)

Would running them in batches of 500 potentially avert the issue/appending them to different lists? Would serverless like AWS Lambda or Sagemaker be quicker?

Comment: why can't you do one url at a time and thread or threadpool

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve found a solution.

So I was trying to ‘soup’ 9000 URLs. What I did was iteratively created variables using the globals() function, with the idea of having each variable store 100 soups, so that would be 90 variables with 100 soups each rather than one list with 9000.

I noticed that the first few hundred were very quick and then slowed down, however running 100 at a time and not constantly elongating an already massive list made a difference.

I also got no crashes.

Bear in mind I only tried this with the last 1000 or so after I got stuck at the 8000 mark, but it was so much quicker and no technical issues.

Next time I will initialise a for loop that incorporates each variable and appends eg the 1056th soup to the 11th variable as the 56th element if that makes sense.